# Javascript - How do I clear out a previous value in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm making a game where 2 players are fighting one another.

I have it setup where the document writes the objects hp out (100). However, when I make a event where the player suffers 10 damage, it should write out 90 in the hp bar. Instead it writes out 10090.

How can I get it where the previous value gets updated, rather than it continuing to write beside the previous value?

```
function player (hp, mana, stamina){
    this.hp = hp;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.stamina = stamina; 
    }

function npc (hp, mana, stamina) {
    this.hp = hp;
    this.mana = mana;
    this.stamina = stamina;
    }

var alistar = new player (100, 50, 30);
var dragon = new npc (100, 50, 30);

document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML += alistar.hp;

if ( 0 < 1) {
    alistar.hp = alistar.hp - 10;
    document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML += alistar.hp;
}
```

Doing the = sign works, but it removed any HTML words I had in there. I suppose I can make a 2nd div box for my HTML needs and keep the value seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `=` symbol instead of `+=`:

The `=` operator overwrite the previous value. On the other hand, the `+=` is the union between the `+` operator and the `=` operator, and is the "shortway" to achieve the next:

For example, if you want to add a value to a variable you can do this:

```
var a = 3,
    value = 10; /* Your value, i.e. 10 */

a = a + value; /* a values 13 */
```

**BUT**, you can get the same result using the `+=` operators:

```
var a = 3,
    value = 10; /* Your value, i.e. 10 */

a = += value; /* This adds the value of a to the value of value variable. */
```

As you can think, the value of a is 13, too as the below example.

---

Regarding to your code...

**CODE**:

```
if ( 0 < 1) {
    alistar.hp = alistar.hp - 10;
    document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML = alistar.hp; /* UPDATE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( 0 < 1) {
alistar.hp = alistar.hp - 10;
document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML = alistar.hp;
```

}

+= is concatenating the values and adding them together (seemingly in string format). Instead, you want to use "=" to assign the value of the hp to the hp element, overwriting the existing innerHTML.